# SQL INSERT and UPDATE commands not working on website server, although they are working fine on XAMPP. Page transitions included. PHP website

Tags: javascript, php, sql

On my local machine is running XAMMP (working fine)
(Server TCP/IP, 10.4.17-MariaDB, DB client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.0, PHP version: 8.0.0)

On my website (working but not executing INSERT command)
(Localhost via UNIX socket, 10.3.31-MariaDB, DB client version: libmysql - 5.6.43, PHP version: 7.3.30)

error_log DOES NOT REPORT any errors!(It's empty!)

Here is the code:
DB.php:

```
$DSN='mysql:host = localhost; dbname=myDB; useUnicode=true; characterEncoding=UTF-8; useFastDateParsing=false';

$ConnectingDB = new PDO($DSN,'myUsername','myPass',

    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

On the page (action.php):

```
require_once("includes/DB.php");

    if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      ...
      mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); //I skipped a small part, but I have all arguments set, this part is working fine on both servers

        global $ConnectingDB;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO admins(username,password)";
        $sql .= "VALUES(:username,:password)";
        $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username',$username);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password',$password);
    
        $Execute=$stmt->execute();

        header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

All other commands before and after this code are being executed well on website. Only this INSERT command (and UPDATE on other place) are not being executed. Seems like server just jumps over these lines and continues working without reporting error.

I have incorporated javascript page transitions as well so it could be some interference.
Here is my page-transitions.js:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');

  setTimeout(() => {
    transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
  }, 500);

  for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    const anchor = anchors[i];

    anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let target = e.target.href;

      transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

      setInterval(() => {
        window.location.href = target;
      }, 500);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:
In my table, I haven't set the default values for certain fields. And even though these fields (which had no default values) were not included in my SQL command, the server (Localhost via UNIX socket, 10.3.31-MariaDB, DB client version: libmysql - 5.6.43, PHP version: 7.3.30) ignored the command and continued to execute the code without reporting the error.
On the other hand, my XAMMP (Server TCP/IP, 10.4.17-MariaDB, DB client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.0, PHP version: 8.0.0) executed this code without any problems.
In conclusion, the problem was in the server. I'm still not sure what exactly did cause the problem (I believe it was DB client version or MariaDB version) but now I know that I should keep in mind field default value if I work with older versions of server.
Anyway, I used errorInfo() command in php to locate the error.
My great appreciation to ADyson who pointed me in the right direction. Thanks man.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).